# Cakephp throw exception and property reset

Tags: cakephp, exception

I have a component and with a property test. In a controller I do that :

```
$this->ApiRequest->test = "gg";
throw new NotFoundException;
```

After ExceptionRenderer execution, I try to read the property in beforeRender method of the component :

```
public function beforeRender(Controller $controller) {
echo $this->test;
```

And the property test is empty. If I don't throw the exception, everything works...
Is this normal behavior? How to avoid it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when exception is throw, CakePHP create a new controller.

Answer (score 0):

End if you do this :

```
if (!$this->ApiRequest->exists()) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that's not really my question :/